# Link for first review not showing

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, review

I'm working on a website in Magento 1.9.2. Directly underneath the price on the product pages are links displayed to the reviews and the review-form for that specific product (f.i. 5 review(s) / Add Your Review) When there aren't any reviews available yet there should be a link being displayed 'Be the first to review this product'. Unfortunally this link is not being displayed. The link does show in the tab however.

How can I get the 'Be the first to review this product' link being displayed beneath the price when there aren't any reviews available yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `getReviewsSummaryHtml` function last argument to `true` in `catalog/product/view.phtml` in your theme.

Code will be as follows:

```
 <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'default', true)?>
```